# LINQ join 2 tables having a DateTimeOffset foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I join 2 tables when they are sharing a foreign composite key in the data type **DateTiimeOffset**?

Please, refer to the following query.

```
from o in outstandingOrders
join d in dispatchAdvicedOrders
on new { o.ExpectedDeliveryDate, o.JobNumber } equals new { d.ExpectedDeliveryDate, d.JobNumber } into oD
from d in oD.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new DeliverySchedule
{
    ExpectedDeliveryDate = o.ExpectedDeliveryDate,
    JobNumber = o.JobNumber,
    OutstandingWeight = o.Weight,
    DispatchAdvicedWeight = d.Weight
};
```

Focus on the line

```
on new { o.ExpectedDeliveryDate, o.JobNumber } equals new { d.ExpectedDeliveryDate, d.JobNumber } into oD
```

1. Data Type of the all **ExpectedDeliveryDate** is `DateTimeOffset`
2. Date Type of the all **JobNumber** is `string`

**My Problems**

1. Should I use `DateTimeOffset.Compare()` for the above query?
2. If so, how can I use it?

Comment: I didn't understand very well what is the problem, could you give more details about what is happening? Is there any error being thrown?

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos no error but I suspect results. Will LINQ be smart enough to find the equality of this composite key. Because it is a datetimeoffset. Will there be any additional thing to be done?

Comment: Yes it is smart enough to generate correct join. Try first. `Compare` probably will fail with translation error.

Comment: I mean when I used comparison operators in linq queries for DateTimeOffset fields, it did not gave me the expected results. Then I refactored them to DateTimeOffset.Compate in all the queries. Then it worked properly. So when I use the phrase equals with the same DateTimeOffset fields, I suspect it will go crazy again!!